# What is the difference between vector space and dual space?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, dual-spaces

I read that in Dirac notation, kets are elements of a vector space and bras are elements of the dual space. My question is, what is the difference between vector space and dual space, and why are bras elements of the dual space?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is a set $V$ with operations $+$ and $\cdot$ satisfying the vector space axioms. Given a vector space $V$, it's dual space $V^\star$ is defined as $\mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathbb{F})$, i.e. the set of all linear maps(functionals) between the vector space and its underlying field(considered as an own vector space in this case).

Normally, the Dirac notation $\langle v|w\rangle$ is a representation of a scalar product and the *Bra* and *Ket* correspond on a low level to vectors input in this scalar product. Note, that for the complex scalar product, order of the arguments is important due to its hermitian nature and its semi-bilinearity, i.e. that it is conjugate linear w.r.t. to one argument. A classical way is to define the standard complex scalar product to be conjugate linear in the second argument. In Bra-Ket-notation, you usually reverse the order of the arguments of the complex scalar product, i.e. $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y|x\rangle$ resulting in conjugate linearity in the first argument.

---

The key thing is that there is a strong correspondence between scalar products and members of the dual space, i.e. linear functionals.

There is a way that any functional corresponds in a one-to-one fashion to a representation using the scalar product(of the associated vector space). This is known as [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

More precisely, you may look at a vector $v\in V$ and suppose that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an associated scalar product(turning $V$ into a euclidean/unitary space in the real/complex case). Then the map $\varphi_v:w\mapsto\langle w,v\rangle$ is a member of the dual space $V^\star$ and the theorem says that any linear functional $\psi\in V^\star$ can be written as such a $\varphi_v$ uniquely.

Thus, you may convert a scalar product between two vectors into an application of a linear functional to another vector, pulling the problem statement into the realm of dual spaces, where you have other mathematical possibilities to tackle various questions.

**EDIT:** Note, that the definition of $\varphi_v$ of course depends also on the argument which is assumed to be conjugate linear, in this case the second, as linearity in the first is needed to make $\varphi_v$ a linear map(check this).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, how silly of me to write a name in lower case.

Comment: thank you for your answer.... ...I understand that that with ket we work in linear space...but when we built a relation as you write"φv:w↦⟨w,v⟩ is a member of the dual space V⋆" between ket and its conjugate bra ,we will have dual space

Comment: @yanaghanim I don't really know what you're asking or why you re-decided in accepting the answer but I would like to resolve any issues you might have with the concept.

Comment: thank you ...I want to now what the meaning of dual space...why we use it with bra not with ket???

Comment: @yanaghanim I've edited my answer to add some more information. For the complex scalar product, order of the arguments is important due to its hermitian nature and its semi-bilinearity, i.e. that it is conjugate linear w.r.t. to one argument. Note that the Bra-Ket-notation usually reverses the order of the arguments of the complex scalar product, i.e. $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y|x\rangle$. This is more a notational detail. It is more fruitful, I think, to understand the nature of the correspondence between the dual space and scalar product.

Answer (score 2):

For the finite dimensional case we have for a column vector $u$:
$$
u = \vert u \rangle\\
u^+= \langle u \vert
$$
where $u^+$ is the transposed, complex conjugated, thus adjugated, vector.
It is a linear form from $V$ to the scalar field.

If $V$ is a vector space then $V^*$, consisting of all linear forms of $V$, is a linear vector space as well.